# Can't switch to other Branch because of Untracked working tree files

Tags: git, github, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

i have Created Sub module which should it's content from other git Repo after Creating it and it seem everything is good when i try to Switch to another Branch it give me error

```
> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks checkout Feature/7-SOE_Update --progress
> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
> Application_Layer/Appl_SOC/SOC_Algorithm/SOC_Basic.c
> Application_Layer/Appl_SOC/SOC_Algorithm/SOC_Basic.h
> Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
> Aborting``
```

i try to use git status to see what's happening
--give me up to date
i tried to use ignore = dirty inside .git module file
--still i can't switch to other branch
i tried to switch by force
-- deleted my untracked files

this is the only solution that worked for me
git submodule deinit --all
git pull
rm -rf build
rm -rf $RETDEC_INSTALL_DIR
but when i switch back to the branch and try to switch to other branchs again the problem return again which doesn't make any sense to repeat this every time to switch to this branch.

also inside this sub module only three files that have untracked state but other files are fine didn't complain about them which i see not making sense at all i mean it should complain about all files right?

Comment: if you find my answer solving your problem don't forget to accept it (the checkbox)

Answer (score 1):

Git tries to checkout the same files that aren't tracked in your current branch. The files could be left from unfinished merges, etc. Git gives you a recipe even:

```
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
```

You could `git clean` then try to checkout again. Make sure you didn't put any work you need in those files.

`git clean` could give you

```
fatal: clean.requireForce defaults to true and neither -i, -n, nor -f given; refusing to clean
```

Just repeat with `git clean -f`.

If you're not sure that you want to remove all untracked files you could go interactive:

```
git clean -i
Would remove the following item:
  ufff
*** Commands ***
    1: clean                2: filter by pattern    3: select by numbers
    4: ask each             5: quit                 6: help
What now>
```

or you can run it dry to see which files will be removed and see that you won't remove any files you need to keep:

```
git clean -n
Would remove ufff
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean

Comment: using Clean Command didn't give me any output which mean there is nothing but as i try to checkout to other branch still give me the Same Error.error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout.

Comment: @MahmoudAli try `git reset --hard` it will reset all your files to the latest commit (will delete your current changes!). then try to checkout. i usually use both `git reset` and `git clean`

Comment: but what if those files has been Deleted i want them in my project.i'm fraid using --hard will remove the files. also i tried to use git reset --soft origin/branch name but still has the same problem

Comment: @MahmoudAli `git reset --hard` doesn't delete your committed changes so you're safe. if you want to save the current changes then use `git stash` and `git stash pop` to bring your changes back after the checkout

Comment: still didn't work even i use git reset --hard. i tried also $ git stash --include-untracked  git reset --hard git clean -fd then i pull  git pull